# How to create most appealing mobile app design

Tags: android, android-layout, photoshop

I am a android developer and i have a very short knowledge of photoshop and other designing tool. I have not much interest in designing. But to make my own android app i will have to put myself in designing phase.

Please tell me what should i learn or practice so that i will make my application look better than now.

Please also tell me about font styling and font sizes. Which one is better android native font/styles or Robotic fonts? I mean to say that which one will look better.

Comment: Please google your thought , here we will guide in programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at

1. The official designing guide  [here](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)
2. A slideshow [here](http://www.slideshare.net/retomeier/being-epic-best-practices-for-building-android-apps)
3. A pdf [here](http://www.unifiedtestinginitiative.org/files/uti_best_practices_v1_final.pdf)

Comment: The official one is a very useful document to read when you're in the designing fase. I highly recommend using the Actionbar. If you have to be compatible with pre-honeycomb, I highly recommend using the ActionbarSherlock http://actionbarsherlock.com which makes the ActionBar available on pre-honeycomb.

Answer (score 0):

Just play around with the build in Editor (Eclipse). Place some buttons, set some settings and take a look at the xml-tab to understand what happens. That's the way how you can get basic knowledge.

For further information, read through the official documents: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html